# How to combine each subarray of subarrays and store them as comma separated strings?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping, array-column

I need to join all subarray `Name` values in single subarray.

Given input format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => kumar
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => siva
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Arun
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Prem   
                )
        )
)
```

required output format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => kumar, siva
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Arun, Prem 
                )
        )
)
```

My coding attempt:

```
$final = array();
foreach ($NameArray as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $rows) {
        $final[] = $rows['Name'];
    }
}
print_r($final);
```

It shows each separate. I need each subarray to be a single array name with comma format.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you have so far, along with the result you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
foreach($a as $k1=>$ar1){
    $text = '';
    foreach($ar1 as $t){
        $text .= "{$t['Name']}, ";
    }
    unset($a[$k1]);
    $a[$k1][0]['Name'] = substr($text,0,-2);
}

var_dump($a);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)

      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'Name' => string 'kumar, siva' (length=10)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'Name' => string 'Arun, Prem' (length=9)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved succinctly with one loop and the implosion of the columnar values in each subarray.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MbG6A))

```
$a = [
         [['Name' => 'kumar'],['Name' => 'siva']],
         [['Name' => 'Arun'],['Name' => 'Prem']]
     ];

foreach ($a as $i => $group) {
    $result[$i][] = ['Name' => implode(', ', array_column($group, 'Name'))];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Name' => 'kumar, siva',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Name' => 'Arun, Prem',
    ),
  ),
)
```